# Symfony3 - Saving a collection

Tags: symfony, collections, persist

I have a little problem. I have an object "persona" who has several collections.
I have a form who render all the collection and allow me to add and remove collections.
After that, I dump all the information and the object "persona" has all the collection I sent it when I submitted the form.
When I persist and flush the data, doctrine saves persona but not the collection

This are my configurations:

**Entity persona**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonaDomicilio",mappedBy="idPersona",cascade={"persist"},orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $domicilios;

public function __construct() {
    $this->domicilios = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getDomicilios() {
    return $this->domicilios;
}

public function addDomicilio(PersonaDomicilio $persona_domicilio) {
    $persona_domicilio->setIdPersona($this);
    $this->domicilios[] = $persona_domicilio;
}

public function removeDomicilio(PersonaDomicilio $persona_domicilio) {
    $this->domicilios->removeElement($persona_domicilio);
}
```

**Entity PersonaDomicilio**

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Persona
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Persona",inversedBy="domicilios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_persona", referencedColumnName="id_persona")
 * })
 */
private $idPersona;
```

**The PersonaType**

```
->add('domicilios', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => PersonaDomicilioType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => false

            ))
```

**The controller action**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $persona = new Persona();
    $formulario = $this->createForm(
        PersonaType::class, 
       $persona,
        array('action' => $this->generateUrl('persona_create'),
              'method' => 'POST')
    );

    $formulario->handleRequest($request);

    $persona->setFisicaJuridica('F');
    $em->persist($persona);
    $em->flush();
```

I don´t wanna persist all the collection manually with a foreach, because the cascade persist would help to do that.
I have to say that I did several tests and I can´t understand why is not working.

Pd: "id_persona" is correctly setted to the collections too.

Answer (score 0):

This is "normal". If you refer to this [old symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) (which is still valid), you also have to persist your PersonaDomicilio (see the paragraph Doctrine: Ensuring the database persistence).

Here is their example :

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Controller/TaskController.php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

// ...
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $task = $em->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Task')->find($id);

    if (!$task) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No task found for id '.$id);
    }

    $originalTags = new ArrayCollection();

    // Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database
    foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag) {
        $originalTags->add($tag);
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {

        // remove the relationship between the tag and the Task
        foreach ($originalTags as $tag) {
            if (false === $task->getTags()->contains($tag)) {
                // remove the Task from the Tag
                $tag->getTasks()->removeElement($task);

                // if it was a many-to-one relationship, remove the relationship like this
                // $tag->setTask(null);

                $em->persist($tag);

                // if you wanted to delete the Tag entirely, you can also do that
                // $em->remove($tag);
            }
        }

        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();

        // redirect back to some edit page
        return $this->redirectToRoute('task_edit', array('id' => $id));
    }

    // render some form template
}
```

And here an example for your configuration (not tested)

```
<?php

// Create an ArrayCollection of the current domicilios objects in the database
$originalDomicilios = new ArrayCollection();
foreach ($persona->getDomicilios() as $domicilio) {
    $originalDomicilios->add($domicilio);
}

// Check request
$form->handleRequest($request);

// Was the form submitted?
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    try {

        // Handle domicilios
        foreach ($originalDomicilios as $domicilio) {
            if (false === $persona->getDomicilios()->contains($domicilio)) {

                // remove the persona from the domicilio (or remove it)
                $domicilio->removePersona($persona);

                // Persist domicilio
                $em->persist($domicilio);
            }
        }

        // Save new domicilios
        foreach($persona->getDomicilios() as $domicilio){
            if (false === $originalDomicilios->contains($domicilio)){

                // Add persona
                $domicilio->addPersona($persona);

                // Persist domicilio
                $em->persist($domicilio);
            }
        }

        // Persist persona
        $em->persist($persona);

        // Save
        $em->flush();

        ...

    } catch (\Exception $e) {


    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it is an edit action , I have a new action there and the collection would be persisted by default with the cascade persist

Comment: I also have the collections without adding them in my example.

Comment: All I need is to save them

Comment: cascade persist is not enougth. you have to persist for both sizes of the relation (and it works for add or edit action)

Comment: So , I have to persist manually in both cases and in all of my operations, haven´t I ?

Comment: You may not have to persist your domicilios but you have at least to make ->addPersona($persona) to each of them.

Comment: Ok, but I have all the collections in my object persona before persist its without doing  "->addPersona($persona)". If I do this , can I obtain duplicated collections?

Comment: I did what you have said and now I am saving the collections , but when I do "persona->getDomicilios()", I obtain no data and If I go to the BD I have the data, what is the problem now?

Comment: I your addDomicilio function, you have to make a return $this;

Comment: And you should have protected $persona instead of private $idPersona

Comment: I use protected and I also use public but I can´t obtain the data

Comment: Could you provide a fully example code to see how you get the domicilios (certainly in your controller) with persona->getDomicilios() ?

Comment: I saved "persona" persisting collection by collection manually, then I got persona from the repository and I didn´t obtain any domicilio, but if I search PersonaDomicilio doing getRepository('AppBundle:PersonaDomicilio')->findBy([idPersona=> $persona]) I obtain this domicilios , is very frustrating

Comment: I am just expecting to obtain domicilios by the persona object or by doing persona->getDomicilios()

Comment: The problem begins when I do getRepository('AppBundle:Persona')->find($id_persona), because the select didn´t obtain the collections data, so, when the methods getDomicilio for example execute, the data is null